# How do I position these correctly using float in HTML?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to make three sort of blocks using this CSS code:

```
div#menu {
width:200px;
height:400px;
border:2px ridge white;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin:4px;
}
div#container {
width:850px;
height:850px;
overflow:auto;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
border:2px ridge green;
}
div#maincontent {
width:608px;
height:700px;
border:2px ridge white;
text-align:center;
float:right;
top:10px;
margin:4px;
}
div#subcontent {
width:200px;
height:100px;
border:2px ridge white;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin:4px;
clear:both;
}
```

The container will hold the entire project/page.

Inside the container the menu will be to the top left corner, and the subcontent box will be directly beneath the menu (bottom left corner). The maincontent box will be in the top right corner, just to the right of the menu/subcontent box.

I've arranged it something like this, in the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="subcontent"></div>
<div id="maincontent"></div>
</div>
```

However, when I run that, it makes the top of the maincontent box aligned with the top of the subcontent box top, instead of with the menu.

How would I make it float to the top right, instead of just the right?

Comment: Have a look at this question.  It will give you a general Idea on how one can easily layout divs for many scenarios http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731496/css-100-height-and-then-scroll-div-not-page/2731562#2731562  OR this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344825/how-to-build-this-layout-with-css/3344841#3344841

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7zvSu/

Make your mainContent `float:left` (remove the `top` property). And position your main content div right after the menu.

**css:**

```
div#menu {
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    border:2px ridge white;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin:4px;
}
div#container {
    width:850px;
    height:850px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px ridge green;
}
div#maincontent {
    width:608px;
    height:700px;
    border:2px ridge white;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin:4px;
}
div#subcontent {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px ridge white;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin:4px;
    clear:both;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="maincontent"></div>
  <div id="subcontent"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, if you want to float right for a block, always place it before the left float blocks

so if you want to float

```
<div id="maincontent"></div>
```

to right, float this first before the float left divs

the following order of divs should work

```
<div id="container">
<div id="maincontent"></div>
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="subcontent"></div>
</div>
```