# Set html element to have 100% height on page with header

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, height

How can I set an html element to have a 100% height on a page that has a fixed height header? The layout is, of course, not fixed height.

*I already have the `html` and `body` set to simulate `min-height: 100%` correctly.*

---

I have tried the following ideas, but to no avail:

**1.** I have used the following CSS, but it uses a percentage-based height, which doesn't work well because my layout's header is a fixed `81px` in height.

```
#divContent
{
    height: 82%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 82px;
    width: 950px;
}
```

**2.** I have used the following in various combinations of the padding and margin, but all of them expand the height of the page (which is `hidden`), thereby making them all look the same: the bottom `81px` are hidden.

```
html, body
{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 82px;
    padding-bottom: 82px;
}
#divContent
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 82px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-bottom: 82px;
    padding-bottom: 82px;
}
```

I want my `divContent` to consume all of the body's height minus `81px`.

I know how I could immediately do it using tables, but that would be improper use of tables. I also figure that it could be automatically calculated using jQuery, but I haven't written jQuery like that before.

*P.S. I have looked through about a dozen questions and cannot find a solution. If you can prove this is a duplicate that actually covers the same issue, I would gladly read that other post.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the bottom of the div to 0px.  This will expand the div to consume the rest of the page

```
#divContent
{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 82px;
    bottom: 0px;   
    width: 950px;
}
```

Here is a very similar question I answered a while back

[How to build this layout with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344825/how-to-build-this-layout-with-css/3344841#3344841)

Comment: I think you meant to remove the `margin-bottom` and `padding-bottom`. If I remove those, it works! I had previously tried the `bottom` property but while relatively positioning it.

Comment: no not what I meant.  you should set the bottom property with position absolute to have the div consume the rest of the available real-estate.

Comment: (I meant I had previously tried bottom improperly before asking this question.) When I use the CSS in your answer, there is a ton of margin/padding at the bottom of the div. I have to remove it in order to have a "100%" height.

Comment: Well good.   I updated the answer and added a reference for you.