# css difficulties with 100% height

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a page with a panel on the left side.  The panel has a header, a content area and a footer.  The main panel wrapper div is supposed to be 100% of the height of the page.  The header and footer do not have a specified height because I only want them to be large enough for their text and padding while the center content area I want to be 100% of the container minus whatever the height of the header and footer is.  I'm not sure how or if I can do this in css.  Anyone know what to do here?  Thanks.

The html page & css is here - https://gist.github.com/1641918

Comment: See my highly related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391661/set-html-element-to-have-100-height-on-page-with-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use display as table to accomplish this. By setting a height of 100% on the content 'row' and then 0% on the others. Tables try and make their rows match as closely as possible the specified heights.

http://jsfiddle.net/PZALU/

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
div#container { display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
div#container > div { display: table-row; }
div#container > div > div { display: table-cell; border: 1px solid gray; }
div#header { height: 0%; }
div#content {height: 100%; background: lightgray; }
div#footer { height: 0%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this on several occasions. It is *possible* to to with just CSS in one or two specific cases from my experience. Otherwise, you would need to tag team it with Javascript and CSS. Because, in order to set an element to 100% height, its parent element's height must be delared.  Depending on how deeply nested the element is and what siblings it may or may not have before it, will determine if its possible to do with CSS alone.

One method of getting a conent container div to be 100% of the height browser's viewport is via the following styles.

```
html {
  height:100%;
}
body {
  height:100%;
}
#container {
  min-height:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

<html>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It can easily get tricky depending on the layout.