# Fixed header and sidebar, elastic image area, need css help please?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm sure this is obvious to some CSS experts but I'm stuck!

I need a fixed header, sidebar and footer (currently removed) and for the main content area to grow or shrink as required. The problem is the main content area will contain an image and I want it to grow to a maximum, never shrink past a minimum but always take up as much of the maincontent div as possible without getting bigger than the screen size!

At the moment the image is being displayed at full size 1200x800 which runs over the edge of my screen and I am at a loss. Any help much appreciated!

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>page header</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar1">
        <div id="nav">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end #sidebar1 -->
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div class="imagebox">
        <img src="images/image16.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div><!-- end #mainContent -->
    </div><!-- end #container -->
</div>
```

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1550px;
    max-height: 1040px;
    min-width: 951px !important;
    min-height: 538px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tcGreyE #container { 
    background: #333333;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: left;
} 

.tcGreyE #header { 
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #262626;
    padding: 10px 0 0 20px;  
} 

.tcGreyE #sidebar1 {
    float: left; 
    width: 350px; 
    background: #333333;
    padding: 15px 0 0 20px; 
}

.tcGreyE #sidebar1 h3, .tcGreyE #sidebar1 p {
    margin-left: 10px; 
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.tcGreyE #mainContent { 
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 0 370px; 
    max-height: 800px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width:100%;
} 

.tcGreyE .imagebox {
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1200x;  
    max-height: 800px; 
    padding:3px;
}

.imagebox img { 
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at this question.  I believe it is what you are after. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344825/how-to-build-this-layout-with-css/3344841#3344841

Comment: Thanks John but it's not that. Perhaps I wasn't clear. It scales fine if there is just text in the maincontent div. It's when I put an image in there that problems arise. I don't know how to get it to completely fill the available area but not overflow it...

Comment: do you want to keep the aspect ratio?  if so is it more important to scale to height or width?

Comment: Yes.. I think I've solved it (finally!) Sorry, just tracking down how!

Comment: Provide your solution to complete the question.

Comment: The line "width=100%;" should be removed from the #mainContent definition in the css, that fixed it.

That's all it was! Thank you for looking John.

Answer (score 0):

The line `width=100%;` should be removed from the `#mainContent` definition in the CSS, that fixed it.